# How to add Youtube videos to a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, youtube

I have some question about Youtube videos :

1- I want to add some Youtube videos to a table view.

2- I want to add in this table view a subtitle showing the rating number for each video ( like & dislike ) like the attached picture from the old Youtube iPhone built-in app

[image: old Youtube app]

The only difference I want to do is to show the rating in numbers for example: ( Like: 29 , Dislike: 3 ), not in percentage like the old Youtube iPhone built-in app used to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what help do u need here..? what have u done so far..?

Comment: I have created a frame for youtube videos by this code: [ NSString *embedHTML = @"<body style=\"margin:0\"> <iframe height=\"110\" width=\"110\"        src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/HERE YOU PUT THE ID OF YOUR VIDEO\"   frameborder=\"0\"/></iframe></body> "; ] but I don't know how to insert them in a table view like the old youtube iphone built-in app plus I want to show the rating number as a subtitle in the table view cells which shows the recent like and dislike numbers in youtube so it can be up to date.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Youtube API's. For example if you are using searchbar and searching videos related on the basis of related text, then you should use the following link, and parse the obtaining results, I have used NSXML Parser delegates for Parsing. Hope this will help you.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.typeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchBar.text];
    _xmlUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=%@&orderby=relevance&start-index=1&max-results=10&alt=atom",[self.typeString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_xmlUrl]];
    _urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [request release];
    [_searchTableView reloadData];
}
```

## pragma mark - NSXMLParser Delegate Method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
        isEntry = YES;
        isThumbnail=NO;
        isUrl=NO;
        _xmlObject = [[YoutubeData alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"] && isEntry){
        isTitle = YES; 
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:category"] && isEntry){
        isMediaCategory=YES;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"yt:statistics"] && isEntry){
        int totalViewers = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"viewCount"] intValue];
        _xmlObject.songViewers = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",totalViewers];
        int favorite = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"favoriteCount"] intValue];
        float percentage = (favorite*100.0)/totalViewers;
        _xmlObject.songLikePercent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@",percentage, @"%"];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"yt:duration"] && isEntry){
        _xmlObject.songDuraion = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"seconds"];
        NSLog(@"Duration is: %@",_xmlObject.songDuraion);
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:player"] && (isUrl==NO) && isEntry) {
        NSString *strLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
        strLink = [strLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&feature=youtube_gdata_player" withString:@""];
        _xmlObject.songUrl = strLink;
        NSLog(@"Url is: %@",_xmlObject.songUrl);
        isUrl=YES;
    }

    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"] && (isThumbnail==NO) && isEntry){
        _xmlObject.songImage = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"My Thumbnail Url is :%@",_xmlObject.songImage);
        NSLog(@"Images is: %@",_xmlObject.songImage);
        isThumbnail=YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if (isTitle) {
        NSLog(@"Title is: %@", string);
        _xmlObject.songTitle = string;
    }
    else if (isMediaCategory) {
        NSLog(@"Song Id is: %@", string);
        _xmlObject.songType = string;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"] && isEntry) {
        isTitle = NO;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:category"] && isEntry){
        isMediaCategory=NO;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]){
        isEntry=NO;
        [self.youtubeObjects addObject:_xmlObject];
        [_xmlObject release];
        _xmlObject = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have some particular videos which are mine so I'm not planing to put a search bar in my app or show all the content of youtube website, I have an existing app doing this but in a scroll view which I don't really like plus as I said I want show the rating numbers in the table view.so how can I insert my videos in a table view ?

Comment: I want to show the rating in numbers not in percentage as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ok, then you should go for another Youtube API, I think that is for channel. Any way in the above mentioned code, you should check 'favoriteCount' that is the number of likes of a particular video. You should calculate yourself the percentage. You have given the total view and the number of likes.

Comment: Where can I find the youtube channel  API ? Do you think is there API for a playlist because I want to show particular videos not all my videos? Thanks .

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/