# Loading a Youtube Channel

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api

After looking for hours I still can't find a proper example of how I would load a YouTube videos into a `-UItableView` or something similar. Something similar to this http://gyazo.com/cb89587662fab215312c764cda281309 . Does anyone know how to do anything like this or similar  ?

Comment: I have found a smiler question on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477740/how-to-add-youtube-videos-to-a-uitableview) This might helpful to you.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to do this. Is it alright to pay people on this forum to do things for you ? If so I'd pay $50 for anyone that could solve this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [YouTube IFrame Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for iOS.

You can check out [Objective C samples](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample) from YouTube and use YouTube [Objective-C client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).

[Here's a great talk about Mobile best practices for YouTube](http://youtu.be/Bp3i71jaWNo)

Comment: Thanks sir, after looking through this I still have no idea how I could take the information with JSON and upload it into tableViews like this http://gyazo.com/cb89587662fab215312c764cda281309 I'll pay you $70 via PayPal if you can give me some samples or help me via TeamViewer

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

**[IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-youtubeapi/)**

I used this for help when I was starting out with the api for my site.
It uses SimpleXML and PHP, but can with some changes be used with json.

Hope this helps you on your way.